# The # comes out in £ how do i change it to $

Tags: numbers, generator

```
<span id="count"></span>

<script type = "text/javascript">
var num = 1504272.00;
var tim = 0;
function makeNum() {
    var randy = (Math.floor(Math.random()+100)) + 0;  // random amount between 100 and 
    num = ((num*1) + randy).toFixed(2);
    num1 = addCommas(String(num));
    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = "&#163;" + num1;
    tim = window.setTimeout("makeNum()", 1000);  // update once per second
}
function addCommas(nStr) {
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(nStr)) {
        nStr = nStr.replace(rgx, '$1,$2');
    }
    return nStr;
}
function stopit() {
    window.clearTimeout(tim);
}
makeNum();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `&#163;` in your code to `$` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing:

```
"&#163;"
```

To

```
"$"
```